# Invite someone to chat.

Tags: support, chat

Is there a way on this site to invite a user to chat? I know that if there is a long discussion in the comment section of a post then the move to chat feature is available. But can you go into chat directly with another user?

Comment: I am also interested in knowing how to do this. Can someone please answer?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC I gave an answer to my own question for the benefit of others. Hope it helps.

Comment: See also: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that you can make a room with a user and then invite them. However, I am not sure if you can do this with all users.