# How do I invite a user to chat?

Tags: support, chat

Yesterday, discussion in my question's comment section was getting long so I transferred it to chat and had a long talk with another person. Now, if I want to talk to that user in chat what should I do? Is there any way to invite him again to that chat room?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I transferred it to chat". Did you click on the link ["move comments to chat"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983/what-happens-when-the-move-comments-discussion-to-chat-link-is-used) which was automatically offered by SE engine? Or did you manually create a new room for the discussion of your question?

Comment: As with comments also with chat notifications you **must** leave space after the user name otherwise it will not work. There are some exceptions for commas for example but a hyphen (-) is not an exception for all I know. Thus if I want to ping Martin here and I write @Martin-please reply. There just will be no notification.

Comment: I can confirm that I did not receive notification from the above comment. More details can be found [in faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), I will just mention that: "The system does attempt to ignore most punctuation to allow for proper notifications, such as a single trailing dot, comma, or colon." So I would get notification if quid wrote: Can you come to chat, @Martin?

Comment: This a reply to your question in the other thread if no symbols are allowed after the username. Basically the comment just above explains it. You can follow it directly by some symbols that would organically follow a name like a comma, a colon, a possessive s construct etc. Details below the link above.

Comment: @quid In the post where I asked you a question I saw another user using colon after name...only a few comments before...by the way thanks for your help...

Comment: Yes, colons work. (At least if they are followed by a space but even regardless I think. Let us abuse Martin's patience to test it. @Martin:can your hear me?) To say that there must be space after the username was directed at your typical hypen construct.

Comment: @quid It will take long time to check with martin (he may not be online)...try it with me...

Comment: It's not that urgent, is it? :-) We cannot test it here. As you will be notified no matter what, and maybe we should not "spam" another thread with this.

Comment: @quid Ok....all right...

Comment: @quid Yes I received the notification.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for the confirmation. It makes some sense this works as a colon cannot be part of a user name (in contrast to a hyphen).

Comment: @quid What happened to that post of MK which had received $-19$ votes...which dealt with his $1$ year suspension...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Many comments got deleted as there were too many comments but it is still around http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/is-this-account-suspension-abuse-of-moderator-power Note that the frontpage http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ does not show questions with very low score. You need to click on "questions" button to see them.

Comment: @quid comments were deleted...so I was having trouble locating the question...

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to invite a user that has a chat-profile to a chat. 
For details on how to do that see [How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

It appears though that you already are in a room with the user you want to contact again, in that case you can just use at-notification, same syntax as with comments. The user then will receive a ping in chat, and it will also create an item in the comment in-box if they are not online in chat. (This does not work indefinitely, that is you cannot ping a user that was not in a room for a long time.)

Comment: I followed the link to [this article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users).  However, I seem to have run into a roadblock and I am wondering if the instructions are still valid
in this several years old article.  The article reads: 
"You might be able to set up a "one-on-one" chat room for you and the user you'd like to contact by visiting their user profile on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) and clicking the "start a new room with this user" button." ...see next comment

Comment: Questions: (1) Is it necessary to go to chat.stackexchange.com, or can a math user instead go to 
https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com?  (2) Once I go to one of those two locations, I am supposed to *then* visit the user's profile.  The only way that I can see to do that is by typing
in their name in the box in the upper right corner of the webpage.  Supposedly, this is supposed to bring up their chat profile.  I am then supposed to click on the link in their chat profile that says "invite them to a chat".  ...see next comment

Comment: Experimenting, I followed the procedure and typed in "quid".  Instead of bringing up the chat profile for
quid, it brought up a page that showed chat messages associated with quid.  Therefore, the instructions seem to be no longer valid.  What is the current procedure for inviting a user to a chat "on-the-fly" outside of any existing mathSE query.

Comment: On the chat page first click on "users" then you can "filter users"

Comment: Thanks quid.  That was the info that I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

As the link in quid's answer explains, you can create a new room for you or another user. I will add that it is also possible to invite a user to already existing room.

You first need to find this users chat profile either by [searching among users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users) (using the box named "filter users"<sup>1</sup>) or simply by clicking on they username in chat.<sup>2</sup>

Notice that then you can see two options there:

- "Invite this user to" with a list of rooms you're currently in. (So do not forget that if you want to invite a user to an already existing you room, you have to be already in this room.
- Start a new room with this user.

[image: screenshot]

<sup>1</sup> On the [page with users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users), you need to use the box for searching users - not the box in the top bar which is used for searching messages. See the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>2</sup>I'll add here that not every user has also a chat profile. Users who never talking chat - and never had comments moved to chat - most likely do not have a chat profile and cannot be contacted in this way. (Moreover, a user has the same username as the parent user. Since some users have different usernames on different sites, it is possible that you might have to try several usernames before you find the right one. However, the users with different usernames on different sites are rather rare, as far as I can tell.)

---

After these general comments, addressing the question in the title, I will add a few more remarks:

- If you have already started a discussion with a specific user in some chatroom (which is the situation described in your post), then you do not need to invite the user to the chatroom. You can simply [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ping/info) the user in that chatroom either by using `@username` syntax or by using reply function. (Some more details can be found, for example, here: [Does ping work in chat with no autocompletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226321) or [Does a direct reply to a message in chat create a notification, no matter what age the message is?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287972))
- If have created a chatroom with the intention to continue discussion you started with some other user in comments - or if you want to use some existing room for this - the reasonable approach is simply to ping the user [in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/comment-replies/info) and include a link to the chatroom. It is possible that some other users who read your discussion in comment might be interested in the same topic, including link to the chatroom provides those users with a link to the place where the discussion continued.