# How could I create a chat-room; and invite a specific user to be there [ofcourse if he, him-self wants]?

Tags: discussion, chat

I have some problems about two questions; which has been asked and answered by the same user.
It is very helpfull, if he gives me some clues to resolve my problems.

> How should I start a chat with him?

Comment: See here: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037)

Comment: @Martin Sleziak ; It seem my question is an exact dupplicate of that question. Thank you so much.

Comment: And unless it is very clear otherwise, best not to ask "him" to chat.  Ask "them" to chat, or ask "her/him" to chat.

Comment: @amWhy ; My dear amWhy, you are right, but In my special case his first name is Steven. Anyway, until now I don't know how to creat a chat-room or find his mail.