# Help using chat room

Tags: support, chat

May I join an already existing chat room (e.g. the [Logic](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) one) and invite another user to talk ?

If so, how ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: See here: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037) However in case of room created by another user, it might be polite to know what the room owner thinks about that before inviting other users.

Comment: You can find link to chat faq and also some other useful links [in this tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/chat/info).

Comment: @MartinSleziak - thanks ! The issue was that I was able to create a new room but in both cases I cannot find how to invite someone. At the end (soway) we succeed. :-)

Comment: Actually, you are currently an owner of the room! So you're already jointed. See: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/44058/logic?tab=access.  And as an owner you can certainly invite other users.

Comment: @amWhy - yes thanks ! We succeeded (with the help of some user...). But the issue is that I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [the Chat FAQ says](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) about *inviting* is interesting but not explicit:

> If you need to invite someone to your room, do it from the user's chat profile page or from the user card that pops up when you click on their avatar in a chat room.

I assumed this meant searching for a user from [the Chat Users page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users).  Although I drilled down to find *myself*, this did not immediately suggest to me a mechanism for issuing an invitation.

Comment: If you have some problems finding *mechanism for issuing an invitation*, perhaps the details explained here might help: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037)

Comment: Thanks, @Martin : your Answer there points out a subtlety I would not have thought about - if I want to invite a user to an existing Chat, I have to be in that room currently for the invitation option to appear.