# Help with Chat and Question

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I am trying to add a user to chat I made because I have a question about his answer he gave a while back to a specific question [Problem Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486839/text-book-possible-error) The person's name is the last answer at the bottom. Do you know how?

Comment: It seems that you're asking about something like this: [How do I invite a user to chat?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22037)

Answer (score 1):

Go to their chat user page, and invite them,  or wait for them to showup ... basically your only options.