# About bans to ask question in math.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, post-ban, se-sites

I was banned from asking questions and it's still continuing. I even don't know whether it's OK to ask this question here. But I can't really distinguish the purposes of different sites of stackexchange. So my questions are:

i) What's the purposes of different sites under stackexchange? Like [https://math.meta.stackexchange.com](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/)  , https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ etc.

ii) Everything has its first time and so had I. I had no idea what a duplicate question is, how to ask a good question. Out of my first six questions, $\ 2$ questions were downvoted and as I was unaware of the consequences of deleting answers consecutive two/three times, I did that and after that I was blocked to ask questions. But after that I did answer some really good questions, my reputations were increased, I won badges. But I am still not unblocked. A beginner doesn't know all these rules and they ask what is not proper in this site violating the rules. Isn't it too harsh to be blocked for so long?

iii) Ways to get out of banning other than editing questions ( in case of editing is not possible.)

Comment: On each SE site, you can find in the help center a clear instruction on the purpose of that site, what can be asked and how to ask question properly.

Comment: Yes it's too harsh, but them's the brakes.

Comment: @amWhy suppose I asked ' prove that $\ a=b$'. There is no way to improve this question. there is no information available that can be added to this question. So for a beginner, it's very hard to understand the policies of the site and  scoring $\ 2/6$ bad questions is not an unusual thing for a newcomer to get banned.

Comment: @amWhy moreover what I think very common may not be very common to you. so downvoting cannot decide ban. yes if I answer wrong or be abusive, I may be banned but this site is for asking questions right? asking intellectual, extraordinary questions are not possible for all. this is not a p.hd class going on. So asking a very general question which is downvoted by some other people should not be an issue to get banned. Yes it may hamper my reputations, my earnings but banning? I think it's too harsh.

Comment: btw thanks though @amWhy. It's not against you but the rules that were made by them.

Comment: I understand @Manjoy.  No one (accept the originator or the algorithm for banning questions) knows exactly how a ban happens.  But it seems clear that deleting questions was framed as a *huge violation*, and I am not sure that that is necessarily appropriate when questions asked were less than ten.

Comment: There are always ways to improve a question, and there is always information that can be added. You can always say how you came to be interested in the question, you can always say what parts of mathematics you already know about, you can always say something about how you tried to solve the problem, how much progress you made, where you got stuck.

Comment: Is the ban gone?

Comment: @Magic_Isa nope

Comment: @ManjoyDas Regarding the title for questions, I'd suggest to be as explicit as possible. e.g. "Uniformly convergence of a series of function." and "Show that the series of functions $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} {x\over n(1+nx^2)} $ is uniformly convergent for all real $x$" so that other users have a better idea of what is it about

Comment: @Magic_Isa the later was my initial  title but even then it was closed.

Comment: @Magic_Isa btw thanks for what you're doing.

Comment: @ManjoyDas You're right about the title, I didn't notice. sorry. // It was closed because of the context: "I am not able to find the sequence $\ {M_n}$ to perform M-test" notice that you didn't show how you weren't able to find the sequence, that is, your attempts and where you were stuck.

Comment: Although your recent edit looks better for sure.

Comment: @Magic_Isa tell me one thing. if i have no clue how to proceed, if i don't know how to find $ \ \{M_n\}_n$, if  i am not able to start a problem, then how i provide a context?

Comment: @Magic_Isa is there any way to chat with someone whom i need?

Comment: @ManjoyDas well in this specific case, you could say what this test is about, what conditions need to hold in order to have uniform convergence, and maybe to provide an alternative solution; also what Gerry said, you could follow that also. // yes, if their gravatar is in chat, then click and then below their gravatar you'll see "start a new room with this user" and click there. See this [also](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22037/how-do-i-invite-a-user-to-chat)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107422/discussion-between-manjoy-das-and-magic-isa).